# convert lighttpd to nginx rewrite rules

Tags: linux, nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I'm trying hard to make my code work on nginx. This configuration works with lighttpd but I want migrate it to nginx.

Rewrite rules on lighttd :

```
url.rewrite-once = (
 "^/(ui)/(.*)$" => "/gi.php/$1/$2",
 "/(.*)\.(.*)" => "$0",
 "/(xhr|js-api)/(.*)" => "$0",
 "^/([^.]+)$" => "/gi.php/$1"
)
```

Can anyone help in this conversion? I tried using lot of things, including converting it to apache rewrite rules, but none of them worked.

Nginx rule:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
       set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
       set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /gi.php/$1 last;
}

Error : 404
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't generally do rewrites in nginx, the same way you do them in Apache or lighttpd. Most such things should be replaced with `try_files` instead.

A trivial example:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /gi.php
```

See the nginx documentation for more details.

Comment: I tried the approach but it didnt work, it worked initially loading the page, but not for others.

Comment: At least you are on the right track now.